# can't get sysctl.conf to set core_pattern

Tags: linux, sysctl

I need to make the following 3 changes to /proc/sys/kernel, and I'm able to make them from the command line fine.  But when I put them into sysctl.conf, only the first 2 take on reboot.

```
kernel.msgmax = 20000
kernel.msgmnb = 64000
kernel.core_pattern="./core"
```

Once the system is up, if I run 'sudo sysctl -p', all 3 values are set.  Is it possible that something in the startup process is changing core_pattern after the initial processing of sysctl.conf is done?  If so, is there some other way to make this permanent?  I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.

@stoney - I tried disabling apport, via /etc/default/apport, and that prevents core_pattern from being overwritten.  But it also seems to prevent core dumps from being generated at all.  Catch-22?  Is there a way to prevent apport from overwriting core_pattern while still supporting core dumps?  If not, setting core_pattern after each system restart does the trick - assuming I remember to do it.  Any thoughts on how to automate this?

Comment: What does `core_pattern` end up being set to? (That wil provide a hint as to what could be setting it.)

Comment: apport overwrites it

Comment: $ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E